# TypeScript: getters added to an object using spread operator return undefined. Functions work fine

Tags: typescript

I am trying to add methods to an object (my use case: I get JSON from an API and want to add functionality to the object). However my getters are failing. Here is an streamlined example of the behavior on TypeScript Playground:

```
let o = {
  a: 'a',
}

let oo = {
  ...o,
  b: 'b',
  fa() { return this.a },
  fb() { return this.b },
  get ga(): string { return this.a },
  get gb(): string { return this.b },
}

console.log(`oo.a = ${oo.a}`)
console.log(`oo.b = ${oo.b}`)
console.log(`oo.fa() = ${oo.fa()}`)
console.log(`oo.fb() = ${oo.fb()}`)
console.log(`oo.ga = ${oo.ga}`)
console.log(`oo.gb = ${oo.gb}`)
```

Output:

```
[LOG]: "oo.a = a" 
[LOG]: "oo.b = b" 
[LOG]: "oo.fa() = a" 
[LOG]: "oo.fb() = b" 
[LOG]: "oo.ga = undefined" 
[LOG]: "oo.gb = b"
```

Why is oo.ga undefined?

Also, I specify the return type on the getters because otherwise I get these errors:

```
'ga' implicitly has return type 'any' because it does not have a return type
annotation and is referenced directly or indirectly in one of its return expressions.
```

Not sure what's going on there either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a bug in TypeScript. Your code (which would work fine in JavaScript) transpiles to:

```
let oo = Object.assign(Object.assign({}, o), {
  b: 'b',
  fa() {
    return this.a;
  },
  fb() {
    return this.b;
  },
  get ga() {
    return this.a;
  },
  get gb() {
    return this.b;
  }
});
```

The problem is the `Object.assign`: using `Object.assign` will result on getters *being invoked* on the objects that are the second (or later) parameters. So the `.ga` property getter gets invoked when the `oo` object is created, not when you access the property to log it later.

```js
const obj = Object.assign({}, { get foo() { console.log('getter invoked'); } });
```

One approach is to set the target to ES2018 or later, which will preserve the rest syntax without the (inaccurate) transpiling to `Object.assign`.

Another option is to manually assign onto the object with getters:

```
let oo = Object.assign({
    b: 'b',
    fa() { return this.a },
    fb() { return this.b },
    get ga(): string { return this.a },
    get gb(): string { return this.b },
  },
o);
```

Comment: @CertainPerformance, so the getters are not actually getters in the created object!! Quite strange it is! Is there a specification/doc for this behaviour?

Comment: @ShivamSingla It is a bug in TypeScript. They *should* be getters, but are getting transpiled incorrectly.

Comment: @CertainPerformance I guess it's issue in vainlla JS. As in your code snippedt of "getter invoked", there is no getter `foo` on the object `obj`. It's just a plain property with value `undefined` (because the getter didn't return anything).

Comment: @ShivamSingla My snippet (in JS) illustrates the problem with the *transpiled code* - getters get invoked when passed as the 2nd (or more) argument to `Object.assign`. That's how things are supposed to work in JS - but TypeScript is transpiling the spread syntax incorrectly. The transpiled `Object.assign` is incorrect.

Comment: @CertainPerformance Yeh, I was founding spec for "That's how things are supposed to work in JS". Found here- https://262.ecma-international.org/11.0/#sec-object.assign There is `Get(from, nextKey)` which is called/invoked on the source object, and  thereby the getter of source object. After that, the value is directly assigned using `Set(to, nextKey, propValue, true)`.